# postgres - select * from existing table - psql says table does not exist

Tags: postgresql

Fresh postgres installation, db 'test', table 'Graeber' created from another program.

I want to see the content of table 'Graeber'. When I connect to the database and try to select the content of 'Graeber', the application tells me : `ERROR:  relation "graeber" does not exist`.

See screenshot:

[image]

What is wrong here?

Comment: Yes because you have to use `"` for capitaletter: `SELECT * FROM "Graeber"`

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try adding the schema as in:

```
select *
from public.Graeber
```

If that doesn't work, then it is because you have a capital letter so try:

```
select *
from public."Graeber"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, i had a similar problem.   the ```select *
from public."Graeber"``` worked for me

Comment: seems that capital letters for table names need to be surrounded with quotes... I didn't need the `public.` part. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks i had this issue with Hive tables all in CAPS. I couldn't figure out why Postgres should would not find them.

Comment: If you want one specific column with case sensitive table names and case sensitive columns:
`SELECT "Graeber"."Name" FROM public."Graeber"`

Comment: `select * from "Graeber"` will also work. No need to add public.

Answer (score 9):

When using the psql console in cmd, sometimes you may forget to add ';' at the end of select statement

Example -1: `select * from user #does not give any result back`

```
select * from user; #this works with ';' at the end
```

Don't take me wrong I faced this issue in Postgresql version 13

Answer (score 3):

See This Example.

```
queuerecords=# create table employee(id int,name varchar(100));
        CREATE TABLE


queuerecords=# insert into employee values(1,'UsmanYaqoob');
        INSERT 0 1


queuerecords=# select * from employee;
    id |    name
    ----+-------------
    1 | UsmanYaqoob
    (1 row)
```